# how can I install lpsolve55 and openturns for python 3.6 in windows 10?

Tags: python-3.x, installation, windows-10, lpsolve, openturns

I want to use the packages lpsolve55 and openturns but they are not working on python 3.6, is there any way to install them for this version of python?

Answer (score 2):

lpsolve is available for python 3.x as well on conda-forge:

`conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install openturns lpsolve55`